# Rebus #17 Needs Deciphering

Tags: visual, rebus

Clean freaks are keen on this property:

[image]

Comment: you can’t put an L which is part of the word in a pictorial rebus that’s just lame

Comment: There are totally pictorial rebuses, semipictorial, and all text.  For the latter, take a gander @ this site:  fun-with-words.com/rebus_puzzles.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you

> Antibacterial

Because

> Ant+Eye+Bacteria+?+l

Comment: Bingo!  You got it!